# Java Beginner - returning array doesn't show the whole array but only the last

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    static int numDie = 2;
    static int sides = 6;
    static String display = "";
    static String a;
    static String[] ary;

    public static String[] spitDie(int x, String s) {
        if (x == 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < sides + 1; i++) {
                a = s + String.valueOf(i);
                ary = a.split("");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i < sides + 1; i++) {
                spitDie(x - 1, s + String.valueOf(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return ary;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] answer = spitDie(numDie, display);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(answer));
        System.out.println(answer[0]);
    }
}
```

It's Dice combination generator code.

The code from `System.out` returns all the `ArrayList`.
[1, 1][1, 2][1, 3]...[6, 3][6, 4][6, 5][6, 6]

However,
last three code just return [6, 6],6,6. it's the last value of the array.

Where did I make mistakes?

I want to put return value in the variable so I can use it for the additional code that I'll enter.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the penultimate `System.out.println` statement in the main method is

> [6, 6]

That's *not* the last value of the array. That's the *entire* array. The entire array `answer` consists of exactly two values: 6 and another 6.

---

I can only guess why you'd think otherwise, but maybe this might help you:

- `ary` is a class member. Each assignment overwrites it's value.
- Note that in Java, as opposed to some scripting languages like php, `ary = <value>` doesn't *append* `<value>` but instead *assigns* `<value>` to `ary`.

Comment: How can I get [1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[2, 6]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[3, 6]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
[4, 5]
[4, 6]
[5, 1]
[5, 2]
[5, 3]
[5, 4]
[5, 5]
[5, 6]
[6, 1]
[6, 2]
[6, 3]
[6, 4]
[6, 5]
[6, 6] from the main method?. I get this array when I print System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary)); from spitDie but not fron main method..
 and How should I call this? Thanks so much Lykanion. I just started learning java. and it's confusing.

Comment: You should probably read up on the debugging techniques that Joe C linked as a comment to your question. And you should read some Java tutorials and/or books.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html might be a start.